# How to mock both static and non-static methods of the same class using Mockery?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm getting this error when running the test below:

**Method doMore  from AA should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.**

I assume this is because the test involves both static and non-static methods of the same class, and I'm not sure how should I proceed. Thank you.

```
 
class Foo {
    public function doThis()   {
        $aa = new AA();
        $result1 = $aa->doSomething(1);
        $result2 = AA::doMore(2);
        return [$result1 ,$result2 ];
    }
}

Class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { 

    public function testDoThis(){
        $mock = Mockery::mock('overload:AA'); 

        $mock->shouldReceive('doSomething') 
        ->once()                            
        ->with(1)                             
        ->andReturn(1);    


        $mock->shouldReceive('doMore') 
        ->once()                            
        ->with(2)                             
        ->andReturn(2);  

        $f = new Foo();
        $result = f->doThis();  
        $this->assertEquals([1,2], $result); 

    }
}
```

Comment: You can call static functions using the `->` notation, so you may want to adjust your `doThis()` function so it uses `->` instead of the `::` notation. 
However static methods are problematic for testing, which is why they are sometimes frowned upon.  You may also wish to pass the `AA` instance in as a dependency (i.e. use dependency injection) rather than instantiate it inside the `doThis()` function.  `new` constructors in your code are often red flags when it comes to testing.

Comment: @Everett Thanks! The `->`  notation works.